# Sinusodial Regression by hand to model data points

Tags: regression, mathematical-modeling

I'm currently working on an assignment, where I am attempting to model COVID-19 cases using sinusoidal regression. I need to create my model by hand and would appreciate any help possible. I've done quite a bit of research online, but all I have found are instructions to have the TI 84 complete this procedure.

I want to model my data using the equation:
=*sin(+)+

Data:
[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwWiM.png)

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByH7n.png)

Comment: The points appear far from your equation model. Moreover they are two outsider points. It is doubtfull that an (even rough) fitting can be obtained. with =*sin(+)+.

Answer (score 0):

The fitting is very bad with the model equation $y=A\:\sin(B_:x+C)+D$.

It can be a little improved with the model equation below. But the fitting remains not good. The scatter is too large and the patern isn't enough regularly repetitive like in a function of sinusoidal kind.

[image]

Comment: What equations could be used to determine the coefficients in the equation? Is it possible to do this by hand as opposed to using other software?

Comment: This requires specialized software for non-linear regression. By hand would be time consuming and tiresome by trial and error.